# Проблема запуска Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, install, восстановление

День добрый господа, сложилась крайне неприятная ситуация с убунту.
Как всегда всё началось с обновления самой системы.
После обновления до 22.0.4 LTS - при запуске убунту висит два варнинга:
Problem blacklisting hash(-13)
/dev/sda5: clean, 220074/3025120 files, 2962839/ 12099399 blocks
И система не стартует. Попытка сноса\переустановки на любую из версий убунты привела к такому же результату.
Убунту стартует из recovery mode.
И тут два вопроса: 1 - как эту беду победить ? 2 - если работать в системе с под recovery mode - файлы\данные будут сохранены или нет?
Железяка у меня такая :
AMD Ryzen 5700x
32 Gb RAM
GeForce RTX 3070TI
Саму убунту ставлю на внешний карман ssd - transcend

Comment: Почему вы уверены, что не стартует? Может, стартует без графического режима? Попробуйте переключиться на другой tty